# Python: Get the following letters in a string and use as key value in dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Let's say for example I have a string "attempt" and I wanted to break it down in to a dictionary to store a letter as a key and the following letters as values in a list.
So I pass the string (s) containing 'attempt' through a function and have the function return a dictionary which looks like

```
{'a': ['t'], 'm': ['p'], 'e': ['m'], 't': ['t', 'e'], 'p': ['t']}
```

they farthest I can get is something like

```
def convert(something):
    dictionary = {}
    for j in range(len(something)):
        if something[j] not in dictionary.keys():
            if i+1 < len(s):
                dictionary[something[j]] = something[j+1]
    return dictionary
```

But that is nowhere near to being close because the output is starting to look like

> {'a': 't', 't': 't', 'm': 'p', 'e': 'm', 'p': 't'}

How would I go about doing this conceptually?

*This is in python 3

Comment: I don't understand how you get that dict from `attempt`. What is the desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) will serve your purposes well:

```
from collections import defaultdict
looknext = defaultdict(list)
s="attempt"
for index, char in enumerate(s[:-1]):
    looknext[char].append(s[index+1])
looknext  # looks like: defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'a': ['t'], 'm': ['p'], 'e': ['m'], 't': ['t', 'e'], 'p': ['t']})
```

How it works (as requested in comment):
`defaultdict` will make a dictionary for you, that when you access one of its items/values, `looknext[char]` e.g., will automatically initialize that value with a `list` (or whatever `default_factory` you pass to its constructor), if the value hasn't been accessed yet. It is functionally equivalent to:

```
try:
    looknext[char].append(s[index+1])
except KeyError:
    looknext[char] = [s[index+1]]
```

Comment: thanks, can you explain how this works so I can understand it instead of just copying and pasting

Comment: @AdminTech, sure, glad to hear you're more for understanding. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution:

```
string = 'attempt'

dic = dict([(letter,[]) for letter in string[:-1]])
```

this gives us

```
>>> dic
{'a': [], 'm': [], 'e': [], 't': [], 'p': []}
```

This takes advantage of the fact that the dictionary definition will overwrite duplicate keys, thus every letter can only be in there once. Now you have a bunch of empty lists, which you then fill with the appropriate content...

```
for i in range(len(string)-1):
    dic[string[i]].append(string[i+1])
```

... by appending (which does not care if there's something in a list already or not). This will also keep the order of letters in the list intact.

There is probably a more elegant solution that uses only one loop, or at least replaces the second one with an implicit formulation as well - but this should do.

**Note**: I tested this in Python 2.7 but afaik it should work exactly the same in 3.x

Answer (score 0):

```
word = 'attempt'
d = {c: [] for c in word}
for current, next in zip(word, word[1:]):
    d[current].append(next)
# -> {'a': ['t'], 'e': ['m'], 'm': ['p'], 'p': ['t'], 't': ['t', 'e']}
```

Note: the last character in the word is also in the dictionary even if its list may be empty in general.